# mac - how to run php exec() with root privileges?

Tags: php, macos, exec, osx-snow-leopard

How to run php's `exec()` with root privileges in mac os?
Here is the command I am testing which does not seem to work:

```
exec("sudo -u root -S ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.2 < /Users/aa/Documents/pass")
```

Comment: Looks like you need to change your architecture as running root commands from PHP is bad  idea...

Comment: what could possibly go wrong?

Comment: Did you try executing the script containing that line as root?  `sudo php -f /path/to/script.php`

Comment: @ohio818 the script is called by apache, and apache is not running as root